# How do I find this WebElement by xpath?

Tags: automated-testing

I need to find the following `WebElement` using an `xPath`.

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddensearch" value="110909" id="searchhidden">
```

The Value is changing dynamically, e.g.

- 109899
- 111910
- 104274
- 102475

Comment: *Not able to find a xpath for this* for what *this* ? Show us your html

Comment: Please read the following about https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask questions on SQA.

Answer (score 1):

dont match the value, match the element that contains the value by ID.

e.g. in the following html

```
<element id="matchthis">value</element>
```

match 'matchthis' not 'value' .

then read the value from the element and check it has the value or values you expect it to have.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML element has an ID. If the page HTML is standards-compliant, that ID will not appear anywhere else on the page.

You can use XPath to narrow things down by using basic logic:

```
<!-- to retrieve the element solely by id -->
//@id="searchhidden"

<!-- to retrieve the input with id = "searchhidden" -->
//input[@id="searchhidden"]

<!-- to retrieve the hidden input with id = "searchhidden" -->
//input[@type="hidden"]| //input[@id="searchhidden"]
```

Any of these XPaths should retrieve your element unless there is another element with the same information in the page.

Comment: In some applications like ExtJS, IDs are assigned dynamically to the page elements on every page load/refresh.

Comment: Given the OP's HTML sample, the value is dynamically generated, not the ID.